# Android In-App Billing v3 Library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, in-app-purchases

Всем привет! В Google play console вылезло уведомление, что нужно перейти на новую версию In-App Billing v3. Кто уже сталкивался? Может у того есть готовый код или знает норм библиотеку на Github? Сейчас я использую https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 но там пока обновлений нет и видимо не будет.
Вот что мне удалось найти на v3 https://github.com/akshaaatt/Google-IAP Но я пишу на Java. Пожалуйста помогите буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Сильно сомнительно, что возможно что-то найти аналогичное тому, что вы используете, т.к. вообще не очень понятно, зачем одну библиотеку в другую оборачивать. Советую просто вручную переписать код на использование последней версии официальной библиотеки. Ну или используйте помянутую вами либу на Kotlin. Её можно и из Java использовать скорее всего.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо за ответ. А вы уже подключали v3 в свои приложения?

Comment: Смотря как определять "подключение". Код писал, оно компилируется, но не запускал) По идее должно работать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Так может вы поделитесь свои кодом, пожалуйста?)

Comment: У меня там слишком сложно - абстракция над 3 библиотеками для покупок (Huawei, гугл, амазон), завёрнутая в RxRelay и раскиданная по 3 flavor. К тому же реализованы только подписки, покупок нет. Также код для гугла ещё не проверялся - он написан, но его никто не тестировал, он может и не работать. Ну и большая часть логики вынесена на сервер, с расчётом на добавление iOS подписок. Вряд ли вам такой код как-то поможет)